# Iteration for x value in equation

Tags: python, iteration, python-3.4, equation, equation-solving

I've been set a task to iteratively calculate the value of x of the given formula : **x**3 - 3x + 4 = 0** using trial and error.
The code will first plug in -1.5 as its first guess and then work up or down from there to try and get the answer 0. Every time a number is plugged in the equation the code should output "Answer ## is too big/small"

I've started the code but I'm a bit stuck as it only does it twice and then stops. I used a while loop but I don't think I've used it correctly or that it may be the wrong way to go about this problem. Any suggestions/snippets of code will be greatly appreciated.

```
import cmath
end = ''

num = 0
guess = -1.5
calculation = (guess**3 - guess * 3 + 4)
print(calculation)
while calculation < 0:
    print("Guess is too small")
else:
    print("Guess is too large")

while calculation != 0 and calculation < 0:
    guess = guess + 0.1 
    calculation = (guess**3 - guess * 3 + 4)
else:
    guess = guess-0.1
    calculation = ((guess**3)-3*guess+4)
    print(calculation)
```

Comment: Not really related to the question, but as you are comparing floats, this may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595425/what-is-the-best-way-to-compare-floats-for-almost-equality-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unclear exactly what you're looking for, but this should get you started:

```
import cmath

guess = -1.5

#put calculations that you use more than once in a function
def calc(a): 
    return round((a**3-a*3+4),1) #round your result

calculation=calc(guess)

while calculation !=0:
    if calculation<0:
        print('Number is too small')
        guess+=0.1
        calculation=calc(guess)
    elif calculation>0:
        print('Number is too large')
        guess-=0.1
        calculation=calc(guess)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've confused the concepts of `while` and `if`.  You need both for ... well, for what I *think* you're trying to do, try the following outline.

```
while calculation != 0:
    if calculation < 0:
        # Guess is too small; print message and adjust guess
    else:
        # Guess is too large; print message and adjust guess
```

I think you can fill in the logic for each branch of the "if".
Especially note that this will terminate only if you get an *exact* answer.  If you want to work in a little tolerance, you'll have to adjust the exit condition `calculation != 0` to have a little "wiggle room".

Comment: thank you for the comment, I'll have a go. Sorry for the confusion, I'm not very good at explaining things :D

Comment: its doesn't stop printing "your answer is too large"

Comment: when I use the end function it only does it once and stops

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put everything inside a single `while` loop, where you check if your calculation matches the expected result, adjust the guess if not, break the loop if yes.

```
guess = -1.5

while True:
    calculation = ((guess**3)-3*guess+4)
    print(calculation)

    if abs(calculation - 0) < 0.1:
        print("Correct guess: ", guess)
        break

    elif calculation < 0:
        print("Guess is too small")
        guess = guess + 0.1 

    elif calculation > 0:
        print("Guess is too large")
        guess = guess - 0.1
```

Note that I do not compare `calculation == 0` because as you choose a step of `0.1` for `guess`, it's unlikely that your calculation will be exactly `0`. In other words, `calculation == 0` will be always `false` and the loop will never stop. Hence I check that `calculation` is close enough to `0`, using a tolerance value of `0.1` (same of the step used). In python 3.5 or later, you could use [math.isclose](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose) from the math module to perform this same check.